# How do I show mysql value only after decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any mysql function that helps to display value only after .  Suppose if I have a column which has value 45.23 I want only to select .23 as value . The example table can be

```
test_table
45.23
```

Comment: you can consider the number as a string, and use substring_index

Comment: substring_index will not also work because I need to some advance calculation also

Comment: Then, I suggest you explain exactly what your complete problem *is*, and how you tackled it, rather than setting up a Twenty Questions game. It might very well be the case that there is a more efficient overall approach, if only the wider picture was available.

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
select col - floor(col)
```

(You might want to tweak this if you have negative values, using `abs(col - truncate(col, 0))`.)

MySQL also supports the more concise:

```
select col % 1
```

To be honest, though, I've never liked this convention (useful as it is) probably because of my background in discreet mathematics.

Comment: I also thought of putting floor and subracting value using floor and I just wanted to know if there are any other options also

Answer (score 0):

The `RIGHT` works as well. Consider this option.

```
create table numbers(a float);
insert into numbers values (45.23)
select right(a,2) as rem from numbers
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=d4d316704a425a02873b790b196e4c54)